# Azure AD Application with identifier x was not found in the directory x

Tags: symfony, azure, saml

I'm trying to implement a SAML authentification between an Azure AD and a Symfony app.
I have a controller that takes the SAML response and handles the response from the Azure AD.

My Azure AD configuration looks like this:

[image]

What is scribbled is the domain name of my Symfony app.
The url "https://my_domain_name/secure" works.

But when the Azure AD redirects me to my response url after the authentification, it gives me the "AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'https://my_domain_name/secure' was not found in the directory x".

Thanks.

Comment: Is your application ID URI (URI ID D'APPLICATION in your screenshot I guess) https://my_domain_name/secure? Your config in your app is probably wrong. Usually you would use the client id as the identifier.